# split a string delimited by given object type

Tags: string, matlab, split, delimiter, text-processing

How can I split a string into a list of substrings, where the delimiter to split by is a MATLAB object type?

For example:

```
>> splitByType('a1b2c3',type=integer)
['a','b','c']
```

or:

```
>> splitByType('a1b2c3',type=character)
['1','2','3']
```

Comment: could you give more examples?

Comment: I've added a new example, hmm.. essentially if the substrings I want are delimited by characters of type integer, I would get a list of those substrings that were delimited by integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by MATLAB object type. For integers, you can use:

```
a='a1b2c'
regexp(a,'[0-9]+','split')
```

which outputs:

```
ans = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'
```

---

Another alternative is:

```
regexp(a,'\d+','split')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [**`regexp()`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) by passing the corresponding regular expression of the type:

- For integers: `regexp('a1b2c','\d+','split') % or use '[0-9]+'`
- For characters: `regexp('a1b2c','[a-z]+','split')`

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the `regexp` answer, if you are comfortable with regular expressions, but you can also use `strsplit` with a cell array of strings containing the possible delimiters:

```
strsplit(a,cellstr(num2str((0:9)'))')        % digits
strsplit(a,cellstr(char([65:90 97:122])')')  % word characters
```

Also, `strsplit` has a regular expression mode (bizarre! why would you use this over `regexp`?):

```
strsplit(a,'\d+','delim','reg')  % one or more digits
strsplit(a,'\w+','delim','reg')  % one or more word characters
```

Which are equivalent to `regexp(a,'\d+','split')` and `regexp(a,'\w+','split')`.